# How to get a crawler to add findings to cell in CSV document on daily basis?

Tags: python, csv

My website just launched a new simple component that contains a series of links. Every 24 hours, the links update/change based on an algorithm. I'm wanting to see how long a particular link stays in the component (because, based on the algorithm, sometimes a particular link may stay in the component for multiple days, or sometimes maybe it will be present for just one day).

I'm working on building a Python crawler to crawl the frontend of the website where this new component is present, and I want to have a simple output likely in a CSV file with two columns:

1. **Column 1: URL** (the URL that was found within the component)
2. **Column 2: #/days seen** (The number of times the Python crawler saw that URL.  If it crawls every day, this could be simply thought of as the #/days the crawler has seen that particular URL. So this number would be updated every time the crawler runs. Or, if it was the first time a particular URL was seen, the URL would simply be added to the bottom of the list with a "1" in this column)

How can this be achieved from an output perspective? I'm pretty new to Python, but I'm pretty sure I've got the crawling part covered to identify the links. I'm just not sure how to accomplish the output part, especially as it will update daily, and I want to keep the historical data of how many times the link has been seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to learn how to webscrape, I suggest using the `beautiful soup` package for that.
2. You scraping script should then iterate over your csv file, incrementing the number on each url it finds, or adding a new one if its not found.
3. Put this script in a cron job, to run it once every 24 hours.

For 2 you can do something like this

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

links_found = [] # find the links here

filename = 'temp.csv'
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open("myfile.csv") as csv_file, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile)

    # Increment exising

    existing_links = []
    writer.write_row(reader.next())
    for row in reader:
        link = row[0]
        existing_links.append(link)
        times = int(row[1])
        if link in links_found:
            row[1] = str(row[1]+1)
        writer.write_row(row)

    # Add new links
    for link in links_found:
        if link not in existing_links:
            writer.write_row([link, 1])

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help, Ron! I took your advice and learned how to scrape with the BeautifulSoup package, and developed my first scraper. I also took your advice and learned how to set up a cron job. Still have some questions regarding the iteration code you have above as it relates to my script specifically - so I created another question to deal with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827702/how-to-iterate-column-in-csv-output-on-this-beautifulsoup-python-script