# How to iterate column in CSV output on this beautifulsoup Python script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cron

I have a beautifulsoup Python script that looks for href links in a component on a website and outputs those links line-by-line to a CSV file. I'm planning on running the script every day via a cron job, and I'd like to add a second column in the CSV labeled "Number of times seen". So when the script runs, if it finds a link already in the list, it would just add to the number in that column. For example, if it's the second time it's seen a particular link, it would be "N+1" or just 2 in that column. But if it's the first time the Python script saw that link, it would just add the link to the bottom fo the list. I'm not sure how to attack this as I'm pretty new to Python.

I've developed the Python script to scrape the links from the component on all of the pages in a XML sitemap. However, I'm not sure how to iterate on the "Number of times seen" column in the CSV output as the cron job runs the script every day. I don't want the file to be overwritten, I only want the "Number of times seen" column to iterate, or if it's the first time the link was seen, for the link to be put at the bottom of the list.

Here's the Python script that I have so far:

```
sitemap_url = 'https://www.lowes.com/sitemap/navigation0.xml'

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

# def get_urls(url):
page = requests.get(sitemap_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = [element.text for element in soup.findAll('loc')]
# return links
print('Found {:,} URLs in the sitemap! Now beginning crawl of each URL...'\
        .format(len(links)))     

csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['hrefs', 'Number of times seen:'])

for i in tqdm(links):
    #print("beginning of crawler code")
    r = requests.get(i)
    data = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    all_a = soup.select('.carousel-small.seo-category-widget a')
    for a in all_a:
         hrefs = a['href']
         print(hrefs)
         csv_writer.writerow([hrefs, 1])

csv_file.close()
```

**[Current state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIldL.png)** Currently, every time the script runs, the "Number of times seen:" column in the CSV output is overwritten.

**[Desired state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1g0U.png)** I want the "Number of times seen:" column to iterate whenever the script finds a link it's seen in a previous crawl, or if it's the first time that link has been seen, I want it to say "1" in this column in the CSV.

Thanks a ton for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't actually a questing about bs4, but more about how to handle data structures in python.

Your script lacks the part that loads the data you already know. One way to go about this would be the build a dict that has all your hrefs as keys and then the count as value.

So given a csv with rows like this...

```
href,seen_count
https://google.com/1234,4
https://google.com/3241,2
```

... you first need to build the dict

```
csv_list = list(open("cms_scrape.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8"))
# we skip the first line, since it hold your header and not data
csv_list = csv_list[1:]

# now we convert this to a dict
hrefs_dict = {}
for line in csv_list:
    url, count = line.split(",")
    # remove linebreak from count and convert to int
    count = int(count.strip())
    hrefs_dict[url] = count
```

That yields a dict like this:

```
{ 
  "https://google.com/1234": 4,
  "https://google.com/3241": 2
}
```

Now you can check if all hrefs you come across exist as a key in this dict. If yes - increase the count by one. If no, insert the href in the dict and se the count to 1.

To apply this to your code I'd suggest you scrape the data first and write to file once all scraping is completed. Like so:

```
for i in tqdm(links):
    #print("beginning of crawler code")
    r = requests.get(i)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    all_a = soup.select('.carousel-small.seo-category-widget a')
    for a in all_a:
         href = a['href']
         print(href)
         # if href is a key in hrefs_dict increase the value by one
         if href in hrefs_dict:
             hrefs_dict[href] += 1

         # else insert it into the hrefs_dict and set the count to 1
         else:             
             hrefs_dict[href] = 1
```

Now when the scraping is done, go through every line in the dict and write it to your file. It's generally recommended that you use context managers when you write to files (to avoid blocking if you accidentally forget to close the file). So the "with" takes care of both the opening and closing of the file:

```
with open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['hrefs', 'Number of times seen:'])

    # loop through the hrefs_dict
    for href, count in hrefs_dict.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([href, count])
```

So if you don't actually have to use a csv-file for this I'd suggest using JSON or Pickle. That way you can read and store the dict without needing to convert back and forth to csv.

I hope this solves your problems...